# How to blinking the text of UITextview using quartzcore framework

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4

I have few question in xcode 4.2 developing.In that i create one application for that application client required some feature like the Text should be blinked.

- In quartzcore Framework how to blink that text.

  How to solve this problem any body have that idea about this problem try to help for resolve my problem with use of any external library.

In advance Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this problem using Core Animation.

```
CABasicAnimation *basic=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
[basic setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.25, 1.25, 1.25)]];
[basic setAutoreverses:YES];
[basic setRepeatCount:MAXFLOAT];
[basic setDuration:0.25];
[self.imgVArrow.layer addAnimation:basic forKey:@"transform"];
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this :

```
- (void)blinkAnimation:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished target:(UIView *)target
{
    NSString *selectedSpeed = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"EffectSpeed"];
    float speedFloat = (1.00 - [selectedSpeed floatValue]);

    [UIView beginAnimations:animationID context:target];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:speedFloat];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(blinkAnimation:finished:target:)];

    if([target alpha] == 1.0f)
        [target setAlpha:0.0f];
    else
        [target setAlpha:1.0f];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Call my function on the UILabel:

```
[self blinkAnimation:@"blinkAnimation" finished:YES target:labelView];
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXLabel

Comment: In this demo there is no any blinking text but another demos are very useful thanks for shearing your valuable time thanks.